# Getting Error: Attribute ktype_motors exceeded max length

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, product-import

In my Magento Project at the time of updating products to the store programmatically, I am getting below import error:

> **Following Error has occurred during the importing process:**

> **Attribute ktype_motors exceeded max length**

My product data array is as follows:

```
=> Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 73400
        [attribute_set_code] => Default
        [sku] => cjc-motor
        [name] => Motor 2013 Audi Seat A4 8K Q5 Exeo ST 2,0 TDI CJC CJCA CJCB CJCC CJCD
        [ebay_name] => Motor 2013 Audi Seat A4 8K Q5 Exeo ST 2,0 TDI CJC CJCA CJCB CJCC CJCD
        [ebay_motors_name] => Engine 2013 Audi Seat A4 8K Q5 Exeo ST 2.0 TDI CJC CJCA CJCB CJCC CJCD
        [ebay_fr_name] => Moteur 2013 Audi Seat A4 8K Q5 Exeo ST 2.0 TDI CJC CJCA CJCB CJCC CJCD
        [description] => 
        [ebay_fr_description] => En cas de Retrait du Moteur, après Examen, que le Prix d'achat sera remboursé.
        [short_description] => 
        [price] => 1799.0000
        [special_price] => 1300.0000
        [weight] => 104.0000
        [status] => 1
        [url_key] => motor-2013-audi-seat-a4-8k-q5-exeo-st-2-0-tdi-cjc-cjca-cjcb-cjcc-cjcd
        [ktype] => "31585","11060","31956","33413","22766","25508","30996","23301","30994","31350","31000","25454","33418","30006","33412","11058","31957","26848","30390","31588","31352","58562","59563","59572","59566","59567","59633","59642","59263","59264"
        [ktype_motors] => "31585","11060","31956","33413","22766","25508","30996","23301","30994","31350","31000","25454","33418","30006","33412","11058","31957","26848","30390","31588","31352","58562","59563","59572","59566","59567","59633","59642","59263","59264"
        [delivery_time] => 3-5 Tage
        [oe_nummer] => 
        [motorcode] => CJC CJCA CJCB CJCC CJCD
        [fahrzeug_typ] => A4 8K Q5 Exeo ST
        [fahrzeug] => Audi Seat
        [baujahr] => 2013
        [baureihe] => ab 11/2007
        [laufleistung] => 29.000
        [leistung_kw] => 88 - 110
        [leistung_ps] => 120 - 150
        [image] => /p/1/p1630863_4.jpg
        [additional_images] => /media/catalog/product/p/1/p1630861_3.jpg,/media/catalog/product/p/1/p1630862_3.jpg,/media/catalog/product/p/1/p1630863_4.jpg,/media/catalog/product/p/1/p1630860_4.jpg,/media/catalog/product/p/1/p1630859_4.jpg,/media/catalog/product/p/1/p1630858_4.jpg
        [qty] => 1
        [product_type] => simple
        [product_websites] => base
        [base_image] => /p/1/p1630863_4.jpg
        [small_image] => /p/1/p1630863_4.jpg
        [thumbnail] => /p/1/p1630863_4.jpg
    )
```

How to solve this error?